# « Avant que » et « après que » : indicatif ou subjonctif?

Tags: grammaire, conjonctions, subjonctif, mode-grammatical, indicatif

Pourquoi les locutions « avant que » et « après que » ne sont pas suivies d'un verbe conjugué selon le même mode ? Alors qu'*avant que* doit être suivi du subjonctif, *après que* quant à lui doit être suivi de l'indicatif ou du conditionnel. L'utilisation de plus en plus fréquente de « après que » + subjonctif n'aide pas à garder cette règle en mémoire.

Quelle en est donc la raison grammaticale ?

Comment: I highly suggest watching [Merci, professeur!](http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/lf/merci_professeur.php?id=2609&id_cat=6) with *Bernard Cerquiglini*.

Comment: Bonjour, voici un cas où peut-être le subjonctif pourrait être remplacé par le futur ? "I am not going to write a guide-book, feeling sure that Mr. Murray will do New England, and Canada before many more seasons have passed by." Je ne vais pas écrire un guide, sachant que M. Murray visitera la Nouvelle-Angleterre et le Canada avant que de nombreuses saisons **se soient** écoulées. Je ne vais pas écrire un guide, sachant que M. Murray visitera la Nouvelle-Angleterre et le Canada avant que de nombreuses saisons **se seront** écoulées.

Comment: See https://redd.it/91gbnx.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

La prémisse de cette question est erronnée : « après que » n'est pas forcément suivi de l'indicatif, même si c'est l'usage le plus courant.

En général, « avant que » réfère à un évènement qui n'est pas encore survenu. Il est donc hypothétique, incertain, donc on utilise le subjonctif. Cet aspect est tellement dominant que la conjonction « avant que » est toujours suivie du subjonctif, même dans les cas où l'évènement est avéré (« il ouvrit la porte une minute avant que nous arrivions¹ »).

Le cas de la conjonction « après que » est plus compliqué. La plupart du temps, elle réfère à un évènement passé, donc certain, et est donc suivie de l'indicatif. Néanmoins, au XXe siècle, des auteurs tels que Camus ou Mauriac ont employé le subjonctif.

> Telle avait été en tout ceci l'innocence du professeur que beaucoup de Coustous, dont aucun n'avait voulu assister au mariage, affectèrent de répondre à son salut après qu'il eût trahi. [Mauriac, *Génitrix*, 1923, p. 333].
>   Après que tu m'aies abandonnée, j'ai d'abord fui le couvent pour la montagne.
>   [CAMUS, *La Dévotion à la croix*, adapté de Calderon de la Barca, 1953, p. 578.]

Les grammairiens ne sont pas unanimes sur la raison de la montée de l'emploi du subjonctif. Certains y voient une simple fusion de l'usage entre « avant que » et « après que », qui sont sommes toutes symétriques (« A avant que B » est largement synonyme de « B après que A ») ; cette fusion est d'autant plus tentante que le mot « que » appelle souvent un subjonctif. D'autres y voient une justification grammaticale : le subjonctif marque la différence de temps entre la proposition principale et la subordonnée (et non ici l'aspect hypothétique de la subordonnée). Certains locuteurs font une distinction entre « après que tu m'aies abandonnée, j'ai d'abord fui le couvent pour la montagne » (évènement qui a un rapport causal avec la proposition principale) et « après que tu es partie, j'ai gagné la montagne » (simple rapport temporel).

Le [Trésor de la Langue Française](http://atilf.atilf.fr/) a un article plus détaillé sur le mode du verbe après « [après que](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/apr%C3%A8s) ». Les citations ci-dessus en sont tirées.

En tous cas, que l'on soit prescriptif ou descriptif, on peut considérer l'indicatif après *après que* comme préférable, mais en aucun cas comme obligatoire en toutes circonstances.

¹  <sub>ou « arrivassions », pour les amateurs de l'imparfait du subjonctif.</sub>

Answer (score 14):

> *On a commencé à formuler cette règle au seizième siècle, mais en 1680 Richelet écrit encore "Après que peut être suivi de l'indicatif ou du subjonctif"* —
>   Information qui m'a été donnée par Patrick Vannier Service du dictionnaire  (Académie française)

Mon opinion est que cette règle découle d'une mauvaise compréhension de ce à quoi sert vraiment le subjonctif. Il n'a rien à voir avec l'hypothétique, l'incertain, le doute, l'opinion, l'irréalité... la preuve?

- Tu pars et j'en suis désolé. Je suis désolé que tu partes.
- Il a du mérite. Je ne le conteste pas. Je ne conteste pas qu'il ait du mérite.
- Il ne dit rien, cependant il n'est pas sot. Il n'est pas sot bien qu'il ne dise rien.

Dans les subordonnées ci-dessus, on évoque au subjonctif des faits réels.

> *En réalité, l'indicatif nous permet de mettre le verbe dans le centre de la négociation et de présenter des données nouvelles. Les questions sont des mécanismes de négociation de l'information, qui est donc objet de négociation. Avec une question l'énonciateur offre à son interlocuteur un énoncé construit comme informatif, mais qui ne l'est pas encore car l'intonation n'est pas assertive, pour que celui-ci le complète, l'accepte ou le refuse. Le subjonctif de son côté présente les données comme déjà acquises (pré-supposées). Il ne s'agit plus, donc, de négocier sur ces données, mais simplement d'en parler.* —
>   Citation de Francisco Matte-Bon à propos du subjonctif en Espagnol.

Cela est tout aussi valable pour le français, me semble-t-il.

Answer (score 8):

Let us study this example from ["Merci, professeur"](http://www.tv5.org/TV5Site/lf/merci_professeur.php?id=2609&id_cat=6):

> Je prendrai ma décision ...
>
> ... après qu'il sera parti.

He is already gone, this is effective. The indicative mood is for real.

> Je prendrai ma décision ...
>
> ... avant qu'il parte.

He is not yet gone, he would go. The subjunctive mood is for virtual.

Answer (score 5):

La position de l'Académie Française est d'éviter le subjonctif avec "après que", malgré les précédents cités, entre autres, dans cet article. C'est une discussion en cours de débat et, même au sein des immortels, il n'est pas clos, car, même avec cette recommandation, les académiciens avouent qu'eux-mêmes cèdent parfois à la tentation subjonctive; par analogie avec "avant que"…

Answer (score 4):

Le subjonctif signifie la plupart du temps le doute, l'opinion, ou l'hypothétique.

Quand on dit que Pierre est arrivé avant que Paul soit parti, on utilise le subjonctif pour marquer le fait qu'on ne savait pas encore, quand Pierre arrivait, si Paul allait vraiment partir. Au contraire, ce n'est pas le cas quand on utilise "après que".

Answer (score 0):

Si j'ai bien compris les écrits du linguiste Francisco Matte-Bon, l'indicatif sert à présenter et négocier des données, alors que le subjonctif présente des données comme acquises, donc comme non négociables, pour en parler et présenter à l'indicatif de nouvelles informations à son sujet.

Dans cette optique, la citation de Camus donnée par Gilles pourrait donc être expliquée ainsi:

'Après que tu m'**aies** abandonnée': 
information au subjonctif présentée comme acquise et donc non négociable, pour en parler et présenter à l'indicatif une information nouvelle qui, elle, peut être contestée:
'j'ai d'abord fui le couvent pour la montagne.'

'Le fait qu'il **ait** mal à la tête a été signalé au médecin.'
Y a-t-il quelque chose d'hypothétique dans cet énoncé?

Hypothèse: S'il fait beau… / A condition qu'il **fasse** beau…
… nous irons faire une promenade.
Hypothèse négociable dans sa première présentation: 
Oui, mais que pourrait-on faire, s'il ne fait pas beau?
La deuxième présentation de l'hypothèse ne permet pas de la contester, donc emploi du subjonctif 'fasse'.

Toute règle grammaticale qui a des exceptions est fausse. (Je ne parle pas des règles orthographiques.)

Remarque: Trouver des contre-exemples à des règles figées est un sport très amusant. Ainsi que faire confiance à son esprit critique. N'est-ce pas ce que font les scientifiques pour faire avancer la science?

Answer (score -1):

« Telle avait été en tout ceci l'innocence du professeur que beaucoup de Coustous, dont aucun n'avait voulu assister au mariage, affectèrent de répondre à son salut après qu'il eût trahi. [Mauriac, Génitrix, 1923, p. 333]. »

Eh ben le p'tit père Mauriac i' s'est trompé, en mettant l'accent circonflexe de l'imparfait du subjonctif. La forme correcte eût été : après qu'il eut trahi, i.e. le passé antérieur sauf erreur, correct car un temps de l'indicatif. J'émets avec force le même avis pour les autres écrivains apparemment non exempts d'un lapsus calami occasionnel, cités par le TLFi. Il s'agit d'une conséquence bête de l'homonymie ou l'homophonie entre eût et eut, et non d'une règle grammaticale !

Donc : avant que + subjonctif, après que + indicatif, et le français est suffisamment compliqué pour ne pas prendre des fautes même d'écrivains reconnus pour des usages à suivre, s'il vous plaît !

Comment: je n'ai rien contre recevoir un pouce en bas si cela m'apprend quelque chose, là je reste dans l'ignorance totale de la raison de celui-ci, pourtant je ne pense pas avoir écrit de bêtise : le passé antérieur est homophone de l'imparfait du subjonctif ET il peut être employé après « après que » contrairement audit imparfait.