# « Aurais dû être tué » ou « aurais dû être tuer » ?

Tags: grammaire, infinitif, participe-passé

J'aimerais bien savoir quelle phrase est juste.

> C’est moi qui aurais dû être tué à la place d'elle.
>   C’est moi qui aurais dû être tuer à la place d'elle.

Comment: Il s'agit ici d'un passif : auxiliaire être suivi du participe passé du verbe, donc : « être tué ». *Être* ne peut jamais être suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif.

Comment: Juste une précision : "à la place d'elle" se dit "à sa place".

Comment: @Laure un clin d'oeil: « être bon à tuer ». Ça me laisse perplexe; peut-on se passer du « bon » c.-à-d. « être(v.) à tuer » ?

Comment: @Amphiteóth Oui, bien sûr on peut se passer du « bon » : « Elle est à croquer ! ». Être à ( *pour indiquer plus explicitement que l'action est présentement en voie de s'accomplir* - Grevisse). Il s'agit bien sûr ici non pas de « être » mais de « être à ». C'est la préposition *à* qui entraîne l’infinitif. De même « être pour », « être en voie de », « être loin de », etc.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

La première est la correcte. Pour plus de facilité, tu peux toujours **remplacer** les verbes en "er" par un verbe comme "cuire" ou "pendre", dont la nuance **s'entend beaucoup mieux**!

Si tu entends « *cuire* » ou « *pendre* », ça s'écrira « *er* », donc « *tuer* » à l'infinitif.

Si tu entends « *cuit* » ou « *pendu* », ça s'écrira **é**, donc « *tué* » au participe passé.

Exemple:

> C’est moi qui aurais dû être pendu/cuit à la place d'elle. => Correct, donc **é**
>
> C’est moi qui aurais dû être pendre/cuire à la place d'elle. => Incorrect

Petite précision, on dira plutôt « *à sa place* » plutôt « *qu'à la place d'elle* ».

Comment: Le truc de remplacer un verbe du premier groupe (verbes en -er) par un verbe du deuxième ou troisième groupe (verbe en -ir ou -re) ne marche qu'avec des francophones qui ont  une connaissance de la langue parlée par pénétration environnementale. Quand on apprend le français langue étrangère (et c'est évidement le cas de la personne qui pose la question) on ne peut donner qu'une explication grammaticale.

Comment: @Laure oui le truc de remplacer le verbe (personnellement j'utilise mordre/mordu) n'est efficace que pour ceux ayant une large expérience pour comprendre si cela sonne faux ou non. Toutefois, plusieurs francophones de naissance se mélange encore avec -er & -é et utiliser ce truc est assez efficace et rapide. On ne peut assumer que l'OP est en apprentissage de la langue et la réponse devrait rester ouverte. Mais c'est vrai que la réponse aurait dû contenir le fait que -Être ne doit pas être suivi d'un verbe à l'infinitif.

Answer (score 5):

Le groupe verbal de la phrase :

> C’est moi qui aurais dû être tué à sa place.

se décompose ainsi :

**j'aurais dû** : verbe *devoir* qui, selon la règle, doit être suivi de l’infinitif.

**être tué** : infinitif passif du verbe tuer. Le passif se formant du verbe être (au temps ou mode qu'on veut, ici c'est à l'infinitif) suivi du participe passé du verbe.

Comparer:

> J'aurais dû tuer ce moustique avant qu'il me pique. (actif)

et

> J'aurais dû être tué à sa place. (passif)

Comment: Au debut je vous remerci de me rependre ensuit je vous demande m'informer que dans cet phrase "J'aurais dû tuer ce moustique avant qu'il me pique." est-ce que on doit utiliser le tempes passe composse comme "J'aurais dû tuer ce moustique avant qu'il m'a piqué."

Comment: @ArdalanShahgholi « Avant que ne peut pas être suivi du passé composé. La règle est qu'on utilise le subjonctif après « avant que ». Avant qu'**il me pique** est un subjonctif.  [Voir aussi](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/90/358).

Comment: merci vous avez raison