# « Le fait qu'ils satisfassent » : pourquoi le subjonctif ?

Tags: subjonctif

Un professeur a écrit :

> Le fait que *L* satisfasse (*) implique le théorème.

(ici *L* est une fonction spécifique, qui est déjà définie, et (*) et une condition qu'une fonction peut avoir, comme la continuité)

Je ne comprends pas l'utilisation du subjonctif. C'est vrai que *L* satisfait la condition (*), il n'y a pas de doute. Mais je vois que ce n'est pas juste ce professeur, selon Google Ngrams.

Answer (score 2):

En principe, il y a une différence de sens.

> Le fait que L satisfasse (*) implique le théorème.

Si L satisfait (*), alors le théorème est vérifié. Cette formulation n'implique rien quant au fait que L satisfasse ou non (*). Cette phrase énonce juste une implication.

> Le fait que L satisfait (*) implique le théorème.

On sait déjà que L satisfait (*). On en déduit que le théorème est vérifié. D'un point de vue métamathématique, cette phrase énonce une implication, mais d'un point de vue mathématique, elle énonce une conjonction.

Si c'est le deuxième sens qui est voulu et non le premier, le subjonctif est une erreur.

Comment: Je ne suis pas convaincu, je pense utiliser l'indicatif dans certains cas, mais pas ici (que L satisfasse (*) ait déjà été prouvé ou non). J'aurais même au contraire tendance à considérer que l'indicatif maintient l'attention sur L et tend à indiquer que c'est cela qu'on a l'intention de prouver.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Personnellement, je n'utiliserais pas le subjonctif, je dirais quelque chose comme « Si L satisfait (*) alors le théorème est vérifié ». Dans la mesure ou le subjonctif est employé, cela veut dire que l'on n'est pas sûr que (*) est satisfait, soit parce que ce n'est pas tout le temps le cas, soit parce que c'est le cas mais on ne l'a pas encore prouvé.

Answer (score 1):

Naturellement j'utilise le subjonctif pour indiquer que l'intérêt de ma phrase se trouve dans proposition principale (ici il s'agit de l'implication, et implicitement de l'obtention d'une preuve pour le théorème):

> Nous avons prouvé que L satisfait X, or ***le fait*** que L satisf**asse** X implique le théorème.

Je pense que ton professeur a écrit sa phrase dans un scénario similaire.

Dans un scénario différent, j'utilise l'indicatif pour mettre l'attention sur le fait lui même.

> Nous avons montré que ***le fait*** que L satisf**ait** X implique le théorème, montrons donc que L satisfait X.

Dans ce deuxième exemple l'intérêt de la première partie de la phrase est d'indiquer que prouver ce fait est suffisant (l'implication est déjà acquise et n'est pas l'objet de cette phrase).

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens, mais d'intérêt.

Une explication plus générale de ce phénomène est donnée [dans une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23036/79).