# Peut-on utiliser « avant que » dans ce contexte ? Can one use "avant que" in this context?

Tags: choix-de-mot, verbes, mode-grammatical

J'ai vu plusieurs fois le terme « avant que » + subjonctif pour parler du futur. Par exemple :

> Je veux parler avec mon frère, avant qu'il ne parte.

Je veux exprimer que avant un état, il y avait un autre état. En anglais, je dirais :

> "Before I was a doctor, I was a student."

Pour cette situation, est-ce que l'on utilise le terme « avant que » et le subjonctif ? Sinon, que dirait-on ?

Alors, je dirais instinctivement :

> « Avant que j'étais médecin, j'étais étudiant. »

Dans mon exemple, j'utilise l'indicatif. Je veux indiquer aussi que je suis encore médecin, alors je ne suis pas sûr si je dois utiliser l'imparfait ou le présent.

Comment: Puet-être la réponse est-elle déjà [ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/a/90/358).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comme le sujet est le même, il faut dire:

> Avant d'être médecin j'étais étudiant.

Dans les autres cas, on emploie le subjonctif:

> Avant qu'il ne soit trop tard j'ai fait des études.

De manière générale - mais cela peut se discuter et c'est un autre débat -, **si le sujet est le même entre la principale, et la subordonnée, circonstancielle**, etc., on **doit** employer l'infinitif dans la seconde.

Exemples:

> Je veux qu'il mange => OK
>
> Je veux que je mange => Je veux manger.
>
> Je travaille pour que nous vivions => OK
>
> Je travaille pour que je vive => Je travaille pour vivre.
>
> Je réfléchis avec qu'il parte => OK
>
> Je réfléchis avant que je parte => Je réfléchis avant de partir.

Comment: La distinction "même sujet" et "autre cas"  n'est pas pertinente parce que dans une phrase il y a *avant de* et c'est la préposition *de* qui entraîne l’infinitif  et dans l'autre phrase il y a *avant que* qui peut  être suivi soit d'un subjonctif, soit d'une construction avec un infinitif.

Comment: @Laure désolé, mais ce n'est pas lié à la conjonction, c'est tout aussi vrai avec "après que", "pour que", si le sujet est le même => dans ce cas on bascule à l'infinitif.

Comment: Bien sûr que l'emploi de l'infinitif est lié à la **préposition "de"** , on **ne peut pas** avoir de subjonctif après la préposition "de".  La pertinence est entre les emplois de  "avant de" "avant que" et "avant que de". Par ailleurs Grevisse dit que « l'infinitif équivalent à une proposition circonstancielle se rapporte généralement, pour la clarté , au sujet de la proposition principale. Il m'a parlé avant de partir = avant qu'il parte....L'infinitif peut ne pas se rapporter au sujet de la principale, lorsque aucune équivoque n'est à craindre.»

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina Pouvez-vous élaborer votre réponse un peu ? Je suis un peu perdu.

Comment: @PatrickSebastien , autres exemples.

Answer (score 0):

Il faut utiliser le subjonctif

> Avant que je sois médecin, j'étais étudiant.

voire un infinitif (avec *avant de* plutôt que *avant que*) :

> Avant d'être médecin, j'étais étudiant.

Comment: la seconde n'est pas bonne. Il faut un infinitif.

Comment: @guillaumegirod-vitouchkina: Je ne comprends pas ta remarque, il y a bien un infinitif dans la seconde phrase.

Comment: rectificatif: la seconde est la bonne. La première ne peut pas être utilisée.