# Pourquoi le subjonctif est-il utilisé dans ce passage: « mais je comprenais qu’il veuille la punir » ?

Tags: subjonctif, mode-grammatical

Dans *L'Étranger*, un personnage décrit une fille qui l’a trompé :

> Il m’a demandé si je pensais qu’il y avait de la tromperie, et moi, il
>   me semblait bien qu’il y avait de la tromperie, si je trouvais qu’on
>   devait la punir et ce que je ferais à sa place, je lui ai dit qu’on ne
>   pouvait jamais savoir, 
>   **mais je comprenais qu’il veuille la punir**.

Pourquoi le subjonctif ici?

Comment: Est-ce que la fin de cette réponse aide ? https://french.stackexchange.com/a/23036/79

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Partiellement, quoi que la règle qui a provoqué cette utilisation de subjonctif est probablement en jeu ici: "Il a du mérite. Je ne le conteste pas. Je ne conteste pas qu'il ait du mérite."

Comment: "Je ne conteste pas qu'il a du mérite" serait une faute ? Vraiment ? Je serais d'accord pour "Je conteste qu'il ait du mérite". Mais pour la 1ére phrase...

Comment: Un expert de langue pourrait-il/elle mettre ces questions au clair?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dans cette phrase, la personne elle même n'est pas d'accord avec le fait de la punir, "on ne peut pas savoir". De plus la punition n'a pas eu lieu. On est en train de se demander s'il faut punir. Lui, se dit "il faut que je la punisse". C'est bien, à mon avis, un subjonctif.
En fait avec comprendre, tout dépend de son interprétation.
Si c'est au sens de saisir par la pensée, se rendre compte **SANS APPRÉCIATION** → indicatif: "j'ai bien compris ce que vous m'avez dit".
Si c'est au sens de saisir les motifs d’un fait connu, le trouver normal, **L’ADMETTRE** → subjonctif: Je comprends qu’elle l’AIT quitté ("moi pas" me dit Bernard, mais c'est autre chose :)
Voir https://www.etudes-litteraires.com/forum/topic4001-apres-les-verbes-admettre-comprendre-expliquer-et-supposer-indicatif-ou-subjonctif.html