# « Avant que » : mode, temps et aspect

Tags: temps-grammatical, linguistique, mode-grammatical

J'ai une question concernant le mode, le temps et l'aspect dans les subordonnées introduites par *avant que*.

J'ai compris qu'il y a un aspect accompli avec les formes composées et un aspect inaccompli avec les formes simples.

Si on utilise le subjonctif passé avec *avant que*, s'agit-il toujours de l'aspect accompli ?

Exemple :

> Il s'en alla avant que nous ayons pu le remercier.

Comment: Quelqu'un en parle ici vaguement §2 : https://french.stackexchange.com/a/90/17931 Cependant si tu pouvais détailler un peu plus la question, je ne comprend pas bien ce que tu ne comprends pas.

Comment: Je voulais savoir si le subjonctif passé "ayons pu" a l'aspect accompli. J'imagine que c'est le cas (forme composée).

Comment: Il s'agit bien sûr de faits envisagés, mais on peut quand même dire que c'est leur accomplissement qui importe, d'où l'emploi de la forme composée.