# "Après que" avec l' indicatif/subjonctif : différence de sens ?

Tags: sens, subjonctif, indicatif

Bonjour,

J'ai une question concernant le mode après la conjonction *après que* d'un point de vue de sens. Je sais que cette conjonction est selon la norme suivie d'un indicatif, mais que le subjonctif est quand-même beaucoup utilisé. Je me demande s'il y a possiblement une différence de sens entre une subordonnée à l'indicatif et une subordonnée au subjonctif après *après que* ? Que diriez-vous par exemple de la phrase suivante d'abord à l'indicatif (1) et puis au subjonctif (2)?

1. Dans cet ouvrage autobiographique, l' auteur raconte son enfance pendant la Seconde Guerre Mondiale. Petite fille juive, elle est recueillie par une famille belge **après que** ses parents *ont été arrêtés* par la Gestapo.
2. Dans cet ouvrage autobiographique, l' auteur raconte son enfance pendant la Seconde Guerre Mondiale. Petite fille juive, elle est recueillie par une famille belge **après que** ses parents *aient été arrêtés* par la Gestapo.

Y a-t-il possiblement une différence de sens entre l'indicatif et au subjonctif dans ce contexte? Une nuance, par exemple?

Comment: Pas de différence de sens, c'est juste que (1) est plus correct et (2) est plus courant.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'y a pas de différence de sens. Normalement c'est l'indicatif qui doit être utilisé dans ce cas là, mais la plupart des gens utiliseraient le subjonctif et s'attendraient à le lire plutôt que l'indicatif.

Answer (score 0):

[Après que - Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/apres-que)

L’indicatif doit être utilisé à la suite d'après que. L'utilisation du subjonctif est une erreur.

Comment: https://french.stackexchange.com/a/90/358